# How to do this in query Laravel 7?

Tags: sql, laravel-7

select DISTINCT i.filename "Filename", p.ips_acknow_id "ISP Acknow ID"
from isp_acknows i LEFT JOIN pdfreads p ON i.id = p.ips_acknow_id

I could also do this with a join, but I need this format for performance.

```
Note:
1. isp_acknows table
        Schema::create('isp_acknows', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('filename')->nullable();
            $table->string('filedisplayname')->nullable();
            $table->string('privilege')->nullable();
            $table->string('fileversion')->nullable();
            $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

2. pdfreads Table

        Schema::create('pdfreads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('ips_acknow_id');
            $table->unique(['user_id','ips_acknow_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: With Laravel or using Eloquent ?

Comment: return IspAcknow::select('isp_acknows.id','isp_acknows.filename','isp_acknows.filedisplayname','isp_acknows.fileversion','isp_acknows.privilege','isp_acknows.remarks')->LeftJoin('isp_acknows','isp_acknows.id','=','pdfreads.isp_acknows_id')->paginate(1000); I am trying in laravel but fail.

Comment: The docs can help : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins.
It seems `leftJoin` should be with a minus `l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB::table('isp_acknows')
->join('pdfreads', 'isp_acknows.id', '=', 'pdfreads.isp_acknow_id')
->select('isp_acknows.filename', 'isp_acknows.id', 'isp_acknows.filedisplayname', 'isp_acknows.fileversion',
'isp_acknows.privilege', 'isp_acknows.remarks')->where('pdfreads.user_id',$id)
->paginate(1000);